# RMarkdown Officedown: Loop over child document containing flextable with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, flextable, officedown

Is it possible to include a child document in a loop that contains a flextable with UTF-8 encoding?

This is my YAML:

```
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---
```

Without using a loop, it works perfectly and the Delta ("\U0394") is displayed correctly in the output file:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(flextable)

# Create columns
col1 <- c("a", "\U0394")
col2 <- c(1.0, 2.0)

# Create dataframe
data <- data.frame(Parameter = col1,
                   Value = col2)

# Create flextable
ft <- flextable(data)
ft
```
````

To loop over this flextable, I saved the code above as a child file and included it in an asis-chunk with `knit_child()`...

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = "asis"}
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(flextable)

# Read child doc two times
for (i in 1:2){
  out <- knit_child("path_to_child\\child.Rmd", quiet = TRUE)
  cat(out)
  cat("\n\n")
}
```
````

...but then get this error, because the UTF-8 encoding is somehow not recognized anymore:

```
Error in read_xml.character(file) : error parsing attribute name [68]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience using "\u226570" inside a loop. It is due to the aspects of your system locale. Follow this:

1. Use `sessionInfo()` and check the locale information.
2. Change locale to *English_United States.utf8* or other utf8 styles (like *en_GB.UTF-8*) if they are not already set. You can do this using `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English_United States.utf8")`.
3. Check session information again and if locale settings are still unchanged, probably your OS does not support UTF-8 (e.g, updated versions of [Windows](https://blog.r-project.org/2020/05/02/utf-8-support-on-windows/) have better UTF-8 support).

I think your problem would be resolved after setting a valid UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Thanks, this works with R 4.2.1 although getting the warning `In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United States.utf8"): Using locale page other than 1252 may cause problems`.  
It didn't work with older versions, e.g. R 4.0.3, where the warning was: `In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United States.utf8"): OS reports request to set locale to "English_United States.utf8" cannot be honored`.

Comment: @SophieWupper Newer updates of R have better compatibility with UTF-8. You can also install Rtools 4.2 which is used for R 4.2.x (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html). In my case, the latter warning was because I had an outdated OS. UTF-8 support will only work on Windows 10 (November 2019 update) and newer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `flextable_to_rmd`.

See:

- https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html#looping-in-r-mardown-documents
- https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/flextable_to_rmd.html

You have to slightly adjust the code in "path_to_child/child.Rmd":

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, results='asis'}
library(flextable)

# Create columns
col1 <- c("a", "\U0394")
col2 <- c(1.0, 2.0)

# Create dataframe
data <- data.frame(Parameter = col1,
                   Value = col2)

# Create flextable
ft <- flextable(data)

flextable_to_rmd(ft)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it and still get the same error message. I guess it has something to do with "\U0394" because when I replace it with some normal letter, the code works. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Can you check your 2 files are utf8 encoded?

Comment: Yes, I made sure by selecting "File - Save with Encoding - UTF-8".

Comment: OK I am sorry I don't know what happened here. I am on a Mac, it is difficult to reproduce without a windows os

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying. You are right, I'm working on windows.